# Export data from SQL Server to Oracle using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, export

I want to export some data from SQL Server to Oracle but I have this scenario:

My table in SQL I need to save my ID in a parameter in SSIS to use this because I want to run this package every 30 minutes.

So if my last ID in SQL exported to oracle is 10, I will save this on a variable in SSIS to change my query like this `"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID > PARAMETER"`

But I have no idea how to do it. help me

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a variable in SSIS and have it last between sessions.  The ID is in a table, yes?  You can do something along the lines of

```
select 
*
from
table
where 
id > (select max(id) from <destination table>)
```

Or, if you're looking at completely different databases, you can populate a variable with the max(id) from your destination, and then plug that variable into your select from your source.

Comment: I have a **ADO NET Source** and the Data Acess mode iqual to SQL Command. My command returns a TOP 1 DESCENDING from my ID... 

I need to save this result in a VARIABLE... Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: *sorry* Other question: After save the value in the variable, how to use this variable in the SQL Command of **another ADO NET Source**

Comment: You will need to use a variable and build the SQL for it using the id. which would need to be the SQL command for your ADO Net SOurce.

Comment: Hopefully this will help you get started.  [Clicky!](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/).